# AngularJS object as selected input for typeahead

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have input field which I am using for autocomplete and populate on the fly by executing http requests. I am getting such object as example:

```
{
   id:1,
   name:'ABC'
}
```

I want to display `name` for a end user but later on when input has been selected I want to use it as `id` in my further processing. But `ng-model` converts my object into the string and I loose my `id`.

In general all works fine but my issue is that when user select something, lets say string "ABC" it means nothing for me unless I can tied it to "ID" which has been returned by my API. Only if I know ID I can continue future processing.

Could you please help me to figure out, what should I do in order to capture `fromSelected` as object but still show friendly text to user?

Thanks for any help!

Code:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="fromSelected" placeholder="Country, city or airport" typeahead="place.readableName for place in getPlace($viewValue, 'en')" typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" typeahead-no-results="noResults" class="form-control">
```

JS:

```
app.controller('PlaceController', function($scope, $http, searchData) {


    $scope.fromSelected = '';
    $scope.toSelected = '';

    $scope.$watch('fromSelected', function(newValue, oldValue){
        if (newValue !== oldValue) searchData.setTravelFrom(newValue);
    });


    $scope.$watch('toSelected', function(newValue, oldValue){
        if (newValue !== oldValue) searchData.setTravelTo(newValue);
    });


    // Any function returning a promise object can be used to load values asynchronously
    $scope.getPlace = function(term, locale) {
        return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/places/search', {
            params: {
                term: term,
                locale: locale
            }
        }).then(function(response){
            return response.data.map(function(item){

                return {
                    'id': item.id,
                    'name': item.name,
                    'readableName':  item.name + ' (' + item.id + ')'
                };
            });
        });
    };

});
```

Comment: I had only a quick view on your question: Did you tried with `ng-model="fromSelected.name"` and `$scope.fromSelected = {}`?

Comment: @mrak, thanks for answer. If I do so, then my $watch stops working so nothing is captured at all. How do I fix $watch listener?

Comment: You can still use $watch with 'fromSelected.name'

Comment: right, that works thanks! but unfortunately on input change i still can't capture anything but simple string. Probably I need somehow rethink my desing.

Comment: Do you need the $watch at all? You are resolving the promise in getPlace, you could also set the `searchData.setTravelFrom` here?

Comment: `getPlace` returns array of results and data will be displayed to user, at that time I have no idea what he will click.

Comment: Can you make a JSBIN/fiddle/plunkr reproducing the problem?

Comment: It might be problematic because I am using my localhost api to pull data. But in general there are no problem, issue is that when user select something lets say string "ABC" it means nothing for me unless I can tied it somehow to "ID" which has been given by my API, how do I do that?

Comment: you could switch out the $http for a $timeout so as to provide a demo...

Comment: Answer is here! 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32234741/angular-simple-select-issue?noredirect=1#comment52352170_32234741