# Angular simple select issue

Tags: angularjs

I assume it should be a common pattern how people deal with it, but I am surprised why I can't find anything on the internet.

Lets say I have array of objects and I want to display these objects for customer in typeahead window. When customer select something I want to remember customer choice and process further.

Problem: All items displayed in customer readable format - `item.name` (London, Lisbon, Manchester) When customer select something, my `ng-model` `fromSelected` equals just to city string name, which means nothing for me, because I still need `id` for further processing.

Could you please suggest how I can make `fromSelected` be equal to object rather than string but at the same time provide friendly output to user?

```
var app = angular.module("fly");

app.controller('PlaceController', function($scope) {


$scope.fromSelected ='';

$scope.getPlace = function() {

  var items = []
  items.push({
        'id': 1,
        'name': London
      });
  items.push({
      'id': 2,
      'name': Lisbon
      });

 return items;
};

});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="fromSelected" placeholder="Country, city or airport" typeahead="place.name for place in getPlace()" typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" typeahead-no-results="noResults" class="form-control">
```

Comment: your `fromSelected` will have  `place ` selected object..you could simply do  `fromSelected.id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wild Goat,

your typeahead sentence can do that for you. like `item as item.name for item in data | filter:$viewValue`

This basically tells your typeahead to show your `item.name`, but to return your object `item` to the model

This [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pUPzVK?p=preview) will help you doing that

Comment: Solid answer, thanks a lot! Could you please explain what does | filter $viewValue does, if I include it I my typeahead window doesn't get populated or I can't see how it is populated? What could be a reason?

Comment: `$viewValue` as in the documentation is the actual string value in the view. It is passing the filter the value of the view so it can filter your results. Did you try removing it? What was the result?

Comment: When I remove it it works. What is the case when we want to filter on `$viewValue`?

Comment: Good question. I will explain to you based on my empirical tests. If your array is an object (which was my case), you'd need to specify what is the property you want to look for when filtering your list. In short: this is a variable exposed by a directive in an expression that returns results based on a value entered by a user. It is a little bit confusing because you are already setting item.name as your 'filterable value', and that is probably why don't need to tell the filter "hey, filter 'name' according to `'$viewValue'`. Hope this makes sense to you

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot!